# Testing Flask application fails after first test

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, functional-testing, splinter

Just as it sounds, I have a basic functional test suite with two tests. I'm using a small hierarchy to create a shared class called `FunctionalTestBase` which is inherited by two subclasses. In `FunctionalTestBase` I'm using `flask_testing` to import `LiveServerTestCase`, and am also using `Splinter` and `SQLAlchemy`. In my setup method I want to essentially do four things: create a browser that I can use to exercise my application, get my application running, create a database connection, and seed my database.

This is what my setup method looks like:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = Browser(test_browser)
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox
    self.app = self.create_app()
    self.db = db
    self.db.app = self.app
    self.__drop_database()
    self.db.create_all()

    # ...seed data after this...
```

My tearDown method is the following:

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()
    self.db.session.remove()
    self.__drop_database()

def __drop_database(self):
    self.db.reflect()
    self.db.drop_all()
```

My actual test cases exist in the two subclasses, and I'm just using the superclass to share this setup between the two cases/classes. My problem is that when I run both tests, the first test that runs (no matter which one) works perfectly, and the second test never works. It seems to me that there is a crucial piece of the tearDown puzzle that I am missing, and I can't figure out what it is! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to switch to 
[`setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) class methods instead of `setUp` and `tearDown` instance methods.

Comment: That didn't work. And I can't fit them into a class method anyway because my application needs to exist on each test class instance I believe.